# Intersection of rectangle java

Tags: java, intersection

My teacher wants me to find the intersection between 2 rectangles I create. please help me figure out why this doesn't run. the error i get says cannot find variable bottom.

```
public class Rectangle { 

    private int left, bottem, width, height;

    public Rectangle (int l, int b, int w, int h) {
        left = l;
        bottem = b;
        width = w;
        height = h;   
    }

    public int getX() {
        return left;
    }

    public int getY() {
         return bottem;
    }

    public int getW() {
         return width;
    }

    public int getH() {
         return height;
    }

    public int getArea () {
        int area;
        area = (width * height);
        return area;
    }

    public int getPerimeter() {
        int perimeter;
        perimeter = (width + height) * 2;
        return perimeter;
    }

    public int getIntersection (Rectangle one, Rectangle two)  {
         int intxValue;
         int intyValue;
         int intxValue2;
         int intyValue2;
         int area;

         if (one.left + one.width > two.left && one.bottom + one.height > two.bottom) {
               intxValue = two.left;
               intyValue = two.bottom;
               intxValue2 = one.left + one.width - intxValue;
               intyValue2 = one.bottom + one.height - intyValue;
               area = intxValue2*intyValue2;
               return area;
         } else if (one.left+one.width < two.left && one.bottom+one.height < two.bottom) {
               intxValue = one.left;
               intyValue = one.bottom;
               intxValue2 = two.left + two.width - intxValue;
               intyValue2 = two. bottom + two.height - intyValue;
               area = intxValue2*intyValue2;
               return area;
         } else return area;
    }
```

Comment: `bottem` is not the same thing as `bottom`.

Comment: Please show some courtesy to the people you are asking to help you for free and make your code easy to read.

Comment: Oh crap lol spelling mistake :P

Comment: @djechlin Sorry. It looks fine on my computer but when I paste it here it changes the format and I have a tough time on my mac changing the format. I appologise for my ignorance towards how my code looks. This is my first year of it in high school and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the top you have written:

```
bottem = b;
```

Not bottOm.

Next time try to make it easier to help you by formatting the code right.

Comment: thanks :) Sorry its hard to read I'm trying to do this on a mac and its really hard to format. It was fine in my program but when i pasted it here the format changed.